# Oozie Spark2 Java Action : How to Shutdown

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, oozie, apache-spark-2.0

I am migrating my existing pipelines from spark 1.6.0 to spark 2.1.0(cdh 5.15.1).
oozie version that i am  using(4.1.0) does not support spark2 action so we are running the spark2 jobs using java action.

Jobs are getting executed successfully through java action but one problem that i am facing is whenever the oozie workflow is killed, spark application is not getting killed especially when running cluster mode.

I can understand that java action launches the spark driver in a separate container which is  a separate jvm process.
Just want to understand  if there is a way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Sure. That's the **purpose** of the "cluster" execution mode -- to fire-and-forget a long-running job (especially a streaming app) with no string attached to "client" which launched the execution. So you answered your own question, i.e. you should use "client" mode, with the appropriate `oozie.launcher.` properties to get the right container size to fit your driver...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is what happens with all Oozie actions that run as MapReduce jobs. I've experienced the same issue with Hive2 actions.

From O'Reilly's "Apache Oozie"

> If any execution path of a workflow reaches a kill node, Oozie will terminate the workflow immediately, failing all running actions ... and setting the completion status of the workflow to KILLED. **It is worth noting that Oozie will not explicitly kill the currently running MapReduce jobs on the Hadoop cluster that corresponds to those actions.**

And about the Java action

> This action runs as a single mapper job....